# IllegalStateException: Topic(s) [XYZ] is/are not present and missingTopicsFatal is true

Tags: spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka

I have a `Spring Boot` app that tries to read from a local `Kafka` topic.

The app starts to spin up, pauses for 2 minutes and throws the following error:

```
19-11-10 14:49:24.700  INFO 20476 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1573390164696
2019-11-10 14:51:24.793  WARN 20476 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Topic(s) [XYZ] is/are not present and missingTopicsFatal is true
2019-11-10 14:51:24.795  INFO 20476 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2019-11-10 14:51:24.796  INFO 20476 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-11-10 14:51:24.810  INFO 20476 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-11-10 14:51:24.837  INFO 20476 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-11-10 14:51:24.844 ERROR 20476 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Topic(s) [XYZ] is/are not present and missingTopicsFatal is true
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]    
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]  
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE] 
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]  
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE] 
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]    
    at com.example.main(NyApplication.java:38) [classes/:na]    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]    
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]    
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161] 
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]    
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Topic(s) [ZYX] is/are not present and missingTopicsFatal is true    
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.checkTopics(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:366) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]   
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.doStart(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java:136) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]   
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:323) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE] 
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.startIfNecessary(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:309) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]  
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:256) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE] 
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]  
    ... 19 common frames omitted    `
```

The `kafka` runs in a docker on the local computer:

```
 docker run --detach --name kafka -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 --env ADVERTISED_HOST=192.168.1.89 --env ADVERVTISED_PORT=9092 --env AUTO.CREATE.TOPICS.ENABLE spotify/kafka
```

When `bash` into the container

```
docker exec -it 1234567896b5 bash
```

I can see the topic:

```
$/opt/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin# ./kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
$XYZ
```

The topic was created with this command:

```
./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper  localhost:2181 --create --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3 --topic XYZ
```

And I have this  in the `application.yml` of the app (also tried with port 9092):

```
spring:
  kafka:
consumer:
  bootstrap-servers: localhost:2181
  group-id: group_id
  auto-offset-reset: earliest
  key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
  value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
producer:
  bootstrap-servers: localhost:2181
  key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
  value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

Comment: The error message says it's looking for a topic named `users` but your command and listing only have a topic `XYZ`.  All of the `localhost` in this question makes me a little nervous, but unless you have multiple Kafkas running, the likely trouble from that would be connection errors.

Comment: @DavidMaze the users/xyz was a copy/paste issue. Fixed it in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your config is using Zookeeper, not Kafka as the bootstrap servers

Use port 9092, not 2181

Also, that Spotify container is not maintained, so I suggest finding a newer one

Comment: thanks! I change the image to `johnnypark/kafka-zookeeper` and now things are working as expected

Answer (score 22):

set spring.kafka.listener.missing-topics-fatal=false

on your application.yml or application.properties

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation and details to your answer.

Comment: i don't understand how it's so hard to find this propert name (spring.kafka.listener.missing-topics-fatal) , i've literally spent like 20 mins trying to figure out what this prop is called. Any pointers on to a reference page or something like that we can check for others?

Comment: @waqask87 here is some reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html

Comment: I've tried to set the property into an yaml file. can you please give an example of the same property in yaml?

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the answer to the question, but I'm putting this so it can be helpful to someone else.

I faced the same exception even when I used the appropriate port number in the config (9092)

Here's the stacktrace.

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
....

Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Topic(s) [my-cute-topic] is/are not present and missingTopicsFatal is true
```

**The Solution**

I just **created the topic in my local kafka** and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

This might help someone in the future. I am trying to address this error `Topic(s) [yourTopicName] is/are not present and missingTopicsFatal is true`.

You might need to add a bean in your configuration. I had this error and this was my solution - adding a bean of `NewTopic`.

```
@Bean
public NewTopic adviceTopic() {
    return new NewTopic("user", 3, this.replicationFactor);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The yml alternative of the previous answer is:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    listener:
      missing-topics-fatal: false
```