# Topic( s) [xxx] is/are not present and missingTopicsFatal is true

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, jhipster

I'm receiving the following exception when trying to integrate kafka with spring boot:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Topic(s) [pushEvent] is/are not present and missingTopicsFatal is true
```

Based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58789076/illegalstateexception-topics-xyz-is-are-not-present-and-missingtopicsfatal) I've tried to set the the `spring.kafka.listener.missing-topics-fatal` property to `false`. Because I have an jHipster app I added the following configuration into my application.yml:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    listener:
      missing-topics-fatal: false
```

Somehow the above config didn't had an effect and I still receive the above exception.

Am I missing something in the yaml config? Do I need to do something additional?

Comment: Did you create this topic in Kafka broker or do you expect the topic you want to produce message to be created automatically?

Comment: I expect that the topic will be created automatically. When I create manually the topic, the app works ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems topic you are trying to produce message is not created.
You can solve this problem with one of the following options:

- Creating topic manually:

  `bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test`
- Enabling auto topic creation with setting `auto.create.topics.enable` to `true` in broker configs. (config/server.properties file in broker side)

> **auto.create.topics.enable:** Enable auto creation of topic on the server

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the answer given above (that if the topic is not created) and if you're using zookeeper to manage Kafka then just simply execute the command given below.

kafka-topics --create --topic name_of_topic --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1